# ValueError when using pandas' crosstab

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, chi-squared

I'm sure there must be a quickfix for this but I can't find an answer with a good explanation. I'm looking to iterate over a dataframe and build a crosstab for each pair of columns with pandas. I have subsetted 2 cols from the original data and removed rows with unsuitable data. With the remaining data I am looking to do a crosstab to ultimately build a contingency table to do a ChiX test. Here is my code:

```
my_data = pd.read_csv(DATA_MATRIX, index_col=0) #GET DATA
AM = pd.DataFrame(columns=my_data.columns, index = my_data.columns) #INITIATE DF TO HOLD ChiX-result

for c1 in my_data.columns:
    for c2 in my_data.columns:
        sample_df = pd.DataFrame(my_data, columns=[c1,c2])  #make df to do ChiX on
        sample_df = sample_df[(sample_df[c1] != 0.5) | (sample_df[c2] != 0.5)].dropna() # remove unsuitable rows

        contingency = pd.crosstab(sample_df[c1], sample_df[c2]) ##This doesn't work?

        # DO ChiX AND STORE P-VALUE IN 'AM': CODE STILL TO WRITE
```

The dataframe contains the values 0.0, 0.5, 1.0. The '0.5' is missing data so I am removing these rows before making the contingency table, the remaining values that I wish to make the contingency tables from are all either 0.0 or 1.0. I have checked at the code works up to this point. The error printed to the console is:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

If anyone can explain why this doesn't work? Help to solve in any way? Or even better provide an alternative way to do a ChiX test on the columns then that would be very helpful, thanks in advance!

## EDIT: example of the structure of the first few rows of sample_df

```
           col1  col2
    sample1 1   1
    sample2 1   1
    sample3 0   0
    sample4 0   0
    sample5 0   0
    sample6 0   0
    sample7 0   0
    sample8 0   0
    sample9 0   0
    sample10    0   0
    sample11    0   0
    sample12    1   1
```

Comment: Sure, there's a quick fix. How about showing us your data?

Comment: Its basically a dataframe with 2 columns and around 100 rows and all the values are either 1 or 0. The original dataframe 'my_data' is where sample_df is derived from and its similar except with ~3000 columns and has extra rows with the value '0.5', which have been removed in sample_df

Comment: What is samples?

Comment: its just the index of the dataframe, not an actual column of data

Comment: If I call `pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2)` for your sample, I get the expected output.

Comment: what about if you call pd.crosstab(df[c1], df[c2]) where c1 and c2 are variables derived from iterating through the parent dataframe?

Comment: Add a check: `if c1 == c2: continue` Let me know how that goes.

Comment: It returns True, the iteration starts at the 1st col, so sample_df is made up of 2 copies of col 1 from my_data at the first iteration, as expected.

Comment: The problem arises when c1 is equal to c2, then `pd.crosstab` errors out. So, if you fix that, your problem should be solved.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying, ok i've added that into the code and it then works fine on the next column. So it looks like it wont make a crosstab if its given 2 copies of the same column! Is that a bug would you think? Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: No... it kind of makes sense, because a crosstab between the same entity has no meaning. So, are you getting your expected answer? Let me know, and I'll create an answer.

Comment: Yes, it works on the other cols, thanks for that - I guess I could just manually code in 'p=0.0' for that position on the ChiX matrix rather than running it through an actual ChiX calculation. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crosstab between two identical entities is meaningless. `pandas` is going to tell you:

```
ValueError: The name col1 occurs multiple times, use a level number
```

Meaning it assumes you're passing two *different* columns from a multi-indexed dataframe with the same name.

In your code, you're iterating over columns in a nested loop, so the situation arises where `c1 == c2`, so `pd.crosstab` errors out.

---

The fix would involve adding an `if` check and skipping that iteration if the columns are equal. So, you'd do:

```
for c1 in my_data.columns:
    for c2 in my_data.columns:
        if c1 == c2:
            continue

        ...  # rest of your code
```